# Multiple web parts on sharepoint page breaking it

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, google-visualization

I need to create a Dashboard on Sharepoint. I am trying to add multiple web parts, and each web part is a CEWP, with a JavaScript file, which is using Google Charts. However, as soon as I add more than one webpart on the page, the page breaks. Has anyone ever encountered this before? Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you mean "breaks", and what browser are you using?

Comment: I had a similar problem not long ago. Check [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432708/internet-explorer-markup-errors-when-using-google-feed-api-in-master-page). You might also be interested in checking out this that perhaps is related. [The IE10 nosniff issue in SharePoint 2013](https://www.collaboris.com/blogs/collaboris-blog/mark-jones/2013/02/18/the-ie10-nosniff-issue-in-sharepoint-2013#.VO18Y_mG_DF)

Comment: we def. need more information then "breaks". What do the logs say? Are there server errors or client side errors?

Comment: @Daniel, Serv - I try to add another web part, and what it does is starts showing the title of the 1st web part, but the actual chart from the 2nd web part. The 1st chart just dissapears. When I try them individually on a page, they all work fine.