# google visualization google.load weirdness in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, microsoft-edge

I am loading Google Visualization (for the core chart module) and am having issues with Microsoft Edge 20.1040.16384.0.

Here is a pared down version of the page which does nothing other than load the module:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting "Unexpected end tag." on the console reported on line 7 (the close tag on the block that is running google.load

Does anyone have any clue what is going on here?

P.S. The non-pared down version of my page (not shown here) is working fine in Chrome, but there are some issues in Firefox (though no error on the console)... so I am wondering if the Firefox issue might be connected to this. But I figure I can solve this issue and then try to figure out what is happening with Firefox.

Comment: not sure what causes this but it shouldn't be affecting anything, to be sure, move your script to a separate file and include a `src` reference, rather than including the script in the page...

Comment: this issue doesn't appear to be isolated just to Edge but in IE11 as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027821/why-does-google-visualization-cause-html1504-unexpected-end-tag-errors

Comment: A workaround is suggested in [Github issue #2400](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2400)