# Send a chunked HTTPS response from a Go server

Tags: ssl, go, chunked-encoding

The following the example works very nicely for **HTTP**: [Send a chunked HTTP response from a Go server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769626/send-a-chunked-http-response-from-a-go-server)

As soon as I add TLS, I see that the responses are no longer chunked:

```
func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
    if !ok {
      panic("expected http.ResponseWriter to be an http.Flusher")
    }
    w.Header().Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
      fmt.Fprintf(w, "Chunk #%d\n", i)
      flusher.Flush() // Trigger "chunked" encoding and send a chunk...
      time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
    }
  })

  log.Print("Listening on localhost:8080")
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8080", "<CERT_FILE>", "<KEY_FILE>", nil))
}
```

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Can you post something that exhibits the non-chunked response? I've tried your code in my local machine and it works.

Comment: you are using http/2 and that doesn't support chunks

Comment: Thanks for trying this @ssemilla.  I'm executing my code from a docker container.  I'll strip this back and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
log.Infof("Protocol Version: %s", request.Proto)
```

Confirms its using HTTP/2.0

Thanks Vorsprung