# How to set "Transfer-Encoding" in go-revel response header?

Tags: go, http-live-streaming, revel

We are using revel for HLS streaming; while streaming the master playlist, need to set the Transfer-Encoding as "chunked".

With below line, we are able to set the `Content-Type` header;

> c.Response.Out.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl")

However, unable to set `Transfer-Encoding` in the response header.

Any suggestions/example snippets are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not able to set the Transfer-Encoding header? Are there any errors or warnings? When you send that header (which should work the same way as the content type) you should then also correctly send a [chunked http response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26769626). Maybe the framework you use also has an option to do that automatically

Comment: Maybe you also need to add the option [someone mentions here](https://github.com/revel/revel/issues/357)

Comment: @xarantolus I have tested by setting the "Transfer-Encoding" in response and by enabling the conf and tested; but, still the client receives the result as plain text.

Comment: also there is no "Transfer-Encoding" header in client's  Response Header