# Issue: X-Content-Type-Options header missing

Tags: php, html, x-content-type-options

How to fix the issue like X-Content-Type-Options header missing?

Bug detector found this issue.

Answer (score 5):

There are some Web Application Security Platforms (eg. VEGA) detects an issue like Issue: X-Content-Type-Options header missing. When I google for the solution it recommends that it is not a serious issue. And unable to find the proper solution. Finally I found that setting a header will fix the issue. This issue not on html level but on server side. In php we can include the header as below

```
<?php 
     header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');

     ...
     ...

?>
```

And it should be included in all pages.

Comment: read this to find out whal nosniff means: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337630/what-is-x-content-type-options-nosniff