# .htaccess: How to write especial rewrite rule for file downloading

Tags: php, .htaccess

I wanna to create a .htaccess file to be executed when an especial address is requested.
for example when this address is requested: `http://my-website.ir/download/folder2/video22.mp4` I want to change this address to `http://my-website.ir/check-dl.php?folder_name=folder2&file_name=video22.mp4` but I don't want user or his Internet Download Manager to understand this address change.

Comment: may be this link can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187793/force-file-to-download-with-htaccess

Comment: or you can add this code in your .htaccess


`AddType application/octet-stream .csv
AddType application/octet-stream .xls
AddType application/octet-stream .doc
AddType application/octet-stream .avi
AddType application/octet-stream .mpg
AddType application/octet-stream .mov
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf`

Answer (score 0):

Try this by adding the below code in your .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^download/([^/]+)/([^/]+).mp4 /check-dl.php?folder_name=$1&file_name=$2.mp4 [NC]
```

Comment: Can you change your coed? I want folder2 and video22.mp4 be as parameters means if user entered another folder name and another file name theme folder_name and file_name variables should be changed according to the requested address.thank!

Comment: Please try this "RewriteRule ^download/([^/]+)/([^/]+).mp4 /check-dl.php?folder_name=$1&file_name=$2.mp4 [NC]"