# HTTP headers in html/php

Tags: php, html, apache, http

I'm doing penetration testing for a project, and I'm using ZAP. It keeps telling me to set these so I do, but ZAP keeps giving me the same warnings for it.

I used this at the start of the php tag:

```
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
header('X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN');
```

and this at the start of an html file:

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN
```

Can anyone tell me why this isnt working? It worked fine the last time I did this.

Comment: show the warning text

Comment: The Anti-MIME-Sniffing header X-Content-Type-Options was not set to 'nosniff'.
This allows older versions of Internet Explorer and Chrome to perform MIME-sniffing on the response body, potentially causing the response body to be interpreted and displayed as a content type other than the declared content type.
Current (early 2014) and legacy versions of Firefox will use the declared content type (if one is set), rather than performing MIME-sniffing. This is what it gives me for the one, the other is essentially the same thing but for the other option.

Comment: You put THAT in a HTML file?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes, it worked on my last project when I had to address these warnings. This time it isn't, I did it the same way.

Comment: Man, man... What's ZAP first?

Comment: @PraveenKumar It's a tool that my school makes me use to do security testing on my websites. It's called OWASP ZAP.

Comment: look like it's duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337630/what-is-x-content-type-options-nosniff

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I tried doing what that page suggested, but I still get the error. I think I might be putting it in the wrong spot? I put it at the start of the file.