# Disable Chrome strict MIME type checking

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome

Is there any way to disable `strict MIME type checking` in Chrome.

Actually I'm making a JSONP request on cross domain. Its working fine on Firefox but, while using chrome its giving some error in console.

> Refused to execute script from 'https://example.com' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Its working perfectly in Mozilla.. Issue is arising in chrome only

Here are the response Headers of the request..

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:29303
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: xxxx
Expires:-1
Keep-Alive:timeout=5
max-age:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
pragma:no-cache
Set-Cookie:xxxx
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

**Workaround what i think** :
Externally setting content-type to `application/javascript`

Comment: Have you seen this similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github

Comment: @Rory McCrossan yes... that questions refers fetching file from github.. and their is alternate workaround to export file as zip..

Comment: What is the content you're sending as plain text?

Comment: its receiving a json.. response is like this ..`angular.callbacks._3({json_data})`

Comment: I missed you're sending JSONP; you need to use the correct MIME type: `application/javascript`

Comment: I have been struggling with the same error on Spring Boot application.
After reading this [This article](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17575348/spring-boot-and-production-mode-no-components-rendered) I realized it was a spring security issue which was blocking some static resources.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The server should respond with the correct MIME Type for JSONP `application/javascript` and your request should tell jQuery you are loading JSONP `dataType: 'jsonp'`

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528211/refused-to-execute-script-from-because-its-mime-type-application-json-is) for further details !
You can also [have a look a this one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/50017) as it explains why loading `.js` file with `text/plain` won't work.

Answer (score 16):

In my case, I turned off `X-Content-Type-Options` on `nginx` then works fine. But make sure this declines your security level a little. Would be a temporally fix.

```
# Not work
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
# OK (comment out)
#add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
```

It'll be the same for apache.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  #Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This one solution is working fine for me <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  #Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>

Comment: Sure, reduce the security of your site, instead of fixing the actual problem! See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337630/what-is-x-content-type-options-nosniff?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 8):

also had same problem once,

if you are unable to solve the problem you can run the following command on command line
`chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security`

Note: you have to navigate to the installation path of your chrome.
For example:`cd C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application`

A developer session chrome browser will be opened, you can now launch your app on the new chrome browse.
I hope this should be helpful

Comment: Agree.. But only for development perspective .. For production add proper mime types.

Comment: as of this date this flag no longer works to disable MIME type checking

Comment: no working for me either...

Comment: @WurmD that's so annoying !

Answer (score 8):

**For Windows Users :**

If this issue occurs on your self hosted server (**eg:** your custom CDN) and the browser (Chrome) says something like `... ('text/plain') is not executable ...` when trying to load your javascript file ...

Here is what you need to do :

1. Open the Registry Editor **i.e** `Win + R > regedit`
2. Head over to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.js`
3. Check to if the Content Type is `application/javascript` or not
4. If not, then change it to `application/javascript` and try again

Comment: It wasn't there, I've created it and restarted but alas, same error. Edit: I was doing it for pgadmin4 found it In the faq https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/ they suggest `text/javascript`

Answer (score 2):

#### Another solution when a file pretends another extension

I use `php` inside of `var.js` file with this `.htaccess`.

```
<Files var.js>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .js
</Files>
```

Then I write php code in the .js file

```
<?php
// This is a `.js` file but works with php
echo "var js_variable = '$php_variable';";
```

When I got the MIME type warning on Chrome, I fixed it by adding a `Content-Type` header line in the `.js(but php)` file.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');        // <- Add this line
// This is a `.js` file but works with php
...
```

A browser won't execute `.js` file because apache sends the `Content-Type` header of the file as `application/x-httpd-php` that is defined in `.htaccess`. That's a security reason. But apache won't execute php as far as `htaccess` commands the impersonation, it's necessary. So we need to overwrite apache's `Content-Type` header with the php function `header()`. I guess that apache stops sending its own header when php sends it instead of apache before.

Answer (score -1):

Change the route names to single routes in the get handler for `node.js`
My `app.get('/all-produce/search',(req,res))` was not working
but I changed it to `app.get('/getProduce',(req,res))` and the CSS file linked with the html.

Answer (score -2):

In case you are using **node.js (with express)**

If you want to serve static files in node.js, you need to use a function. Add the following code to your js file:

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

Where app is:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
```

Then create a folder called public in you project folder. (You could call it something else, this is just good practice but remember to change it from the function as well.)

Then in this file create another folder named css (and/or images file under css if you want to serve static images as well.) then add your css files to this folder.

After you add them change the stylesheet accordingly. For example if it was:

```
href="cssFileName.css"
```

and

```
src="imgName.png"
```

Make them:

```
href="css/cssFileName.css"
src="css/images/imgName.png"
```

That should work