# disable chrome strict MIME type checking on local dev

Tags: google-chrome, webpack, mime-types

I have a CSS file that my local dev server (webpack) is serving up with apparently the wrong mime type.

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:10001/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' 
because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, 
and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Is there anyway to disable this? I assume it's a chrome setting. At least for a specific host.

Digging into the webpack config, if it doesn't do something basic like this is usually an exercise in frustrating yak shaving.

Most other answers refer to ways of fixing the server. I just want to hack this client side since the server is being stubborn.

related:

- [Disable Chrome strict MIME type checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228657/disable-chrome-strict-mime-type-checking)
- [Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github)

Comment: FYI you can also look at chrome://flags/ for example chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost  helps with certificates but I can't find one for ignoring mime-type mismatches

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your question is from a while ago, but ranks well on Google for this problem so I wanted to chip in with a couple pointers.

### It might be an HTTP/404 in disguise

The error message is probably just misleading you.
It's unfortunate that Google Chrome removes the response entirely, even the preview of the "Network" dev panel.

The MIME type might be incorrect because the server is answering with an HTTP 404 message.
To test: Open the URL to the CSS file in the browser directly, or fetch it with a tool like `wget`.

Have you checked if the path is correct? Depending on your configuration the css file might not be where it was before (Assuming it's not a problem with webpack or its configuration).

I can just guess blindly here what the correct URL might be...
`http://localhost:10001/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css`
`http://localhost:10001/css/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css`
`http://localhost:10001/css/font-awesome.min.css`
`http://localhost:10001/font-awesome.min.css`

### Checking the request header

In general, not just in case of CSS responses:
The request headers can be prepared to gracefully fallback, should a `text/html` response come through (the default Apache 404 page, for example).
`Accept: text/css, text/plain, */*`

But you should *not* configure `*/*` as acceptable for every request. It's not always useful, even on a local development environment - responses of the wrong type should be fixed early.

### Why frameworks want to handle this gracefully

The server may deliver the correct answer, but with an incorrect `Content-Type` header.
The framework assumes the server "must have meant application/json" and lets the JSON parser to its thing anways.

If this works, the framework can just ignore the incorrect `Content-Type` and still function.
The goal of this is mainly to run on shared hosting environments where editing `.htaccess` settings may be impossible.
It's ok if your application handles content types more strict, with the drawback of debugging errors like this from time to time.

### Related answers

If this doesn't help, answers from here were helpful for me:
[Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type)

Comment: thanks for the long lost reply. I don't have that env setup any more so a bit hard to check but will know next time!

Comment: Typical case. SAML http response (HTML) to a CSS or JS request.

Comment: thanks man, you saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same problem and tried many different methods but the issue was i was not adding the `devServer` property to `webpack.config.js` module export.

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: src + '/js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: dist,
        filename: 'js/bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    }
}
```

in this code, without the `devServer` config added, i was getting 404 and Mime-type issue,

adding this resolved the error.

Hope it helps someone troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Hard Reloading or Empty cache and hard reload the page.**

To do that:

1. Open Inspect. (CTRL + SHIFT + I)
2. Right-click on the refresh button(found before address bar) and select the appropriate option.

Comment: Why does that work?