# Why does webpack dev server server CSS bundles with text/html MIME type?

Tags: css, npm, webpack, sass, webpack-dev-server

Because CSS served with `text/html` MIME type by webpack dev server on my development system, Chrome refuses to load them:

`Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/assets/bundles/baseRequirements-a07aa....css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

My webpack confgs:

> webpack.base.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const entries = require('./entries')
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const {VueLoaderPlugin} = require('vue-loader')

module.exports = {
  entry: entries,

  output: {
    filename: '[name]-[hash].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve('./assets/dist/')
  },

  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './assets/webpack-stats.json'}),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: '[name]-[hash].css',
      allChunks: true
    })
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {loader: 'babel-loader'}
      },

      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            'scss': ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
              fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
            })
          }
        }
      },

      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },

      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },

      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: [
            'css-loader',
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                includePaths: [
                  path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'assets/src'),
                  path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'node_modules')
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        })
      },

      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

> webpack.base.config.js

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.config')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/assets/bundles/'
  },

  devtool: 'cheap-source-map',

  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/dist'),
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    port: 3000
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      allChunks: true
    })
  ]
})
```

> packages.json

```
{
  "name": "acme",
  "version": "18.12.2",
  "description": "ACME",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.prod.config.js --mode=production",
    "watch": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.dev.config.js --watch --mode=development",
    "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.dev.config.js --mode=development",
    "lint-staged": "lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "assets/**/*.js": [
      "standard --fix",
      "git add"
    ],
    "assets/**/*.jsx": [
      "standard --fix",
      "git add"
    ],
    "assets/**/*.vue": [
      "standard --fix",
      "stylelint --fix",
      "git add"
    ],
    "assets/**/*.*css": [
      "stylelint --fix",
      "git add"
    ],
    "acme/**/*.py": [
      "black",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "lint-staged"
  ],
  "standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "plugins": [
      "html"
    ],
    "globals": [
      "$",
      "_",
      "log",
      "oTable"
    ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "vue": "vue/dist/vue.common.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "stylelint": {
    "extends": "stylelint-config-standard"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@shopify/draggable": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "accounting-js": "^1.1.1",
    "ansi-styles": "^3.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-slider": "^10.2.1",
    "bootstrap-toggle": "^2.2.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "clipboard": "^1.7.1",
    "css-element-queries": "^0.4.0",
    "debounce": "^1.1.0",
    "fixed-data-table-2": "^0.7.12",
    "get-form-data": "^2.0.0",
    "humanize-plus": "^1.8.2",
    "iframe-resizer": "^3.6.2",
    "inputmask": "^4.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "jquery.mousewheel": "^3.1.9",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "js-storage": "^1.0.4",
    "localforage": "^1.5.5",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "ramda": "^0.25.0",
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dimensions": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
    "react-grid-layout": "^0.13.5",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-select2-wrapper": "^1.0.2",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "select2": "4.0.0",
    "select2-bootstrap-theme": "0.1.0-beta.9",
    "shortid": "^2.2.6",
    "slugify": "^1.3.0",
    "stimulus": "^1.0.1",
    "stimulus-flatpickr": "^1.0.0",
    "uiv": "^0.14.2",
    "urijs": "^1.19.1",
    "url-slug": "^2.0.0",
    "uuid": "^2.0.2",
    "validator": "^10.7.1",
    "video.js": "^7.2.4",
    "videojs-playlist": "^4.2.6",
    "vue": "^2.5.5",
    "vue-strap": "git+https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap.git#v2",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.16.0",
    "vuetable-2": "^1.7.0",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-persist": "^0.6.0",
    "yuglify": "^0.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^5.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.10.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.11.0",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-vue": "^1.2.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "csscomb": "^3.1.7",
    "envify": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^4.17.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0-beta.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^4.0.6",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^7.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "prettier": "1.10.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "standard": "^12.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "stylelint": "^9.3.0",
    "stylelint-config-rational-order": "^0.0.2",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "^3.2.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^1.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.3.1",
    "uglifyify": "^4.0.5",
    "vue-loader": "^15.4.1",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4"
  }
}
```

(I saw a few SO questions about webpack MIME problems, but they mostly revolved around MERN stack (MongoDB, Express, React / Redux, and Node.js) which is nowhere near our Django, Python, MySQL, Vue / Stimulus stack, and the webpack configurations in those didn't resemble ours.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767435/disable-chrome-strict-mime-type-checking-on-local-dev

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I'll check that if I'll run into it again. I see I starred it, so I have been there at that SO entry. As far as I remember when I manually loaded the files they weren't missing (weren't 404)