# Can someone tell me why i'm getting this error in the chrome console :(

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

The application worked perfectly on its own but when i tried to integrate it with my website that runs on localhost right now, it gives me this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Chrome strict MIME type checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228657/disable-chrome-strict-mime-type-checking)

Comment: Are you trying to render the JavaScript file directly?