# Apache web server configuration issue

Tags: apache

Please help me on the below issue.

> (index):1 Refused to apply style from
>   'https://alert.aviva.com.sg/appliance/index.php' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
>   checking is enabled.
>
> 4(index):1 Refused to execute script from
>   'https://alert.aviva.com.sg/appliance/index.php' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
>   enabled. (index):77 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined     at
>   (index):77
>
> 2(index):1 Refused to apply style from
>   'https://alert.aviva.com.sg/appliance/index.php' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
>   checking is enabled.

Comment: So the most simple way to fix error with `strict MIME checking is enabled` is find the code `add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;` in your config file (whether Nginx or Apache or other), comment it and done. But this isn't a good approach ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337630/what-is-x-content-type-options-nosniff?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)). And you should always find out why MIME is incorrect, try `file --mime-type -b filename` and see if MIME is correct if you serve file directly through apache.

Comment: Possible duclipate with [this answer (Disable Chrome strict MIME type checking)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47344894/8460574).