# How to link my CSS to my HTML in a github hosted site

Tags: html, css, github, hosting, github-pages

My problem is that my website that I'm attempting to host with Github pages will not read the CSS that I have linked to it.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://github.com/legoman8304/legoman8304.github.io/blob/master/style.css">
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>I'm under construction!</p>
        <h6>Copyright MIT Licence 2018</h6>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h6 {
  color: navy;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Link repository: [legoman8304.github.io](https://github.com/legoman8304/legoman8304.github.io)

I'm guessing I linked the CSS wrong because when I using inspect element on the site itself it does show `style.css` but when opened it's empty. Any help?

Comment: https://github.com/legoman8304/legoman8304.github.io/blob/master/style.css doesn't exist. It leads to a 404 error.

Comment: oh, let me change it off private...

Comment: It is now public

Comment: Check the answer posted below.

Comment: Men your html code is wrong, your link tag should be inside a <head> tag and everything nested inside the html tag, you should start by fixing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to link your HTML to the github page rendered `style.css` and not the file itself in the repo.

Change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://github.com/legoman8304/legoman8304.github.io/blob/master/style.css">
```

To this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://legoman8304.github.io/style.css">
```

And move that stylesheet reference inside your `<head>` tag.

Comment: It almost worked, but that came up with a new error: ```Refused to apply style from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/legoman8304/legoman8304.github.io/master/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.``` and style.css no longer shows up in sources

Comment: Hmm. hold on. I'll try fiddling with some file in my own GitHub.

Comment: @WyattNulton So I think this issue is not code related or GitHub related anymore but browser related as can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228657/disable-chrome-strict-mime-type-checking

Comment: Darn that's unfortunate. would inline/internal CSS be the way to go?

Comment: Wait. I figured it out. Just replace the above link with this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://legoman8304.github.io/style.css">` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some way:

- Recommend: `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />`
- Use from raw your css with href: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/legoman8304/legoman8304.github.io/master/style.css`