# How can I use github to host an external CSS file?

Tags: javascript, css, git, google-chrome, github

I uploaded my css to github, then went to the file on the site and clicked the raw option. I tried adding it to a webpage, but chrome is giving me the following errors:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain:
> "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/my-repo/master/style.css".

and

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/my-repo/master/style.css with MIME type text/plain. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

What can I do to add this CSS successfully? I'm adding it with javascript too:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
link.setAttribute('href', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/my-repo/master/style.css');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to link my CSS to my HTML in a github hosted site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54115766/how-to-link-my-css-to-my-html-in-a-github-hosted-site)

Comment: I lost like 2 hours figuring this out as well. I had the same problem when trying to serve js files from my github repo. It turns out that raw.githubusercontent is served as  'text/plain' instead of 'application/javascript'. You can see this by checking the 'Content-Type:' response header in your browser.  This was the best solution I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/63621133/1519464

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can host your files on Github Pages, Just go to repo settings[1], find "Github Pages" section and set your branch[2] and click "Save". You will se the info[3]. Then you go to [https://YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME/REPO-NAME](https://igorkowalczyk.github.io) (If you have index.html or any file eg. `/src/css/style.css`) You can load the CSS, JS or other files on any site

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/file/style.min.css">
```

[1]:

[image: Settings]

---

[2]:

[image: Branch]

---

[3]:

[image: Success Info]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a lil' complicated, because you have to get the file through Javascript, then print it into a style tag.
CORB has to do with server configuration, not client.

JS Example:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/my-repo/master/style.css", true);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhttp.status === 200) {
      var link = document.createElement('style');
link.innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    }
  }
}
xhttp.send(null);
```

Answer (score -2):

Lawl, you put it in a link that is connected with your personal account, this link isn't public. (try to put your link into the browser. Make sure to configure your project as public.

Also, make sure to check this similar post:
[How to link my CSS to my HTML in a github hosted site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54115766/how-to-link-my-css-to-my-html-in-a-github-hosted-site)