# Angular 6 : Refused to execute script from 'URL' because its MIME type( ) is not executable, & strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

Getting following error while running .net Core Angular 6 SPA application : 
The value for MIME type is blank :

[image]

**Index.html File :**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>APP</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>
    <div id="startup-message">
      <h1></h1>
      <p><span></span></p>
    </div>
  </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**Package.JSON :**

[image]

**Customer Headers added in Web.Config file :**

```
<customHeaders>
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />  
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />  
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />  
     <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
  </customHeaders>
```

Comment: 99% of the time, this error is server is not giving you the files that angular is requesting js/css/fonts/images

Comment: Your urls seem wrong. The default templates are setup in a way to expect the js files from `~/dist/xxx.js`, not `~/xxx.js`. The SPA middleware will watch for urls starting with `~/dist` and intercept it, to serve the on-the-fly generated files for hot module replacement functionality

Comment: @Tseng so what is the solution ?

Comment: @SagarK where are bundles getting generated? Outside dist folder?

Comment: Not sure of your setup. The ASP.NET Core templates set up the bundle generation out of the box (the build scripts are set within the csproj as Build Tasks). I assume you used your own build pipeline or changed the index.html or Home/Index.cshtml where the *.js files are embedded

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce your problem.You could create a new asp,net core and Angular template app to check whether the problem exists and compare the files.

It is likely that you have wrong url for the js files.

Besides,`X-Content-Type option: nosniff` tells the browser to force the MIME of the resource to be loaded.Try to comment out that.

Refer to [Disable Chrome strict MIME type checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228657/disable-chrome-strict-mime-type-checking)

Comment: exactly my problem... no-sniff was the cause. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configure your static files BEFORE you configure your routes. In other words, something like this:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// nb: configure this first!!
app.UseStaticFiles();
if (!env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
}

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

Comment: Why is it that important ?