# Django cannot find CSS when deployment

Tags: css, django

When I run my project in my localhost it works perfect. But when I deploy iti cannot find css files. That's why looks bad and doesn't get any style. How can I fix it?

**settings.py**

```
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join('static'),)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
...
```

[image: this is my structure]

Note: And I don't know if it is related but there is an error in console:

Refused to apply style from 'https://...ing.com/static/css/signup.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: Do you use nginx in front of gunicorn? If yes, can you share your nginx config?

Comment: No I do not use it

Comment: Ok, so where exactly are you deploying it and what app server do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Adding following snippet into settings.py file may fix your problem:

```
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("text/css", ".css", True)
```

[check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35557243/8401179)

[Also This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39228881/8401179)

Comment: I added this but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

in your STATICFILES_DIRS..you are missing the argument BASE_DIR

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

In your URL you can ass this

```
 from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns = [
           #Your patters
       ]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: which deployment environment are you using?

Comment: Since I didn't do the deployment process, I don't know much about it and I can't get any information. However, the person I asked said it was .NET as environment