# MIME type ('application/json') is not executable

Tags: javascript, json, magento

I'm facing this issue.
Can anyone please let me know how can I resolve this issue:- 
Refused to execute script from '***' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following code in htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff    
</IfModule>
```

For [More information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18337753/3894567)
and [Magento issue with MIME](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144143/mime-type-text-html-is-not-executable-and-strict-mime-type-checking-is-enabl)

Comment: Hi @Sanchit Gupta thanks for your response. I've added your code into the file and now it's working fine on chrome. But still I'm facing the issue in SAFARI. Can you please let me know is there any alternate way to resolve this issue in safari?

Comment: @InderpreetSinghSaini I will check and update the answer soon. But in between if you found the solution please update the answer.