# Font Awesome showing boxes instead of icons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, meta-tags, font-awesome-5

I was creating a web project, and until today I have been creating web projects on Android (Acode App). I always use font awesome in my projects, but this time I am on a PC running Microsoft Edge (I know Edge's not the best for debugging) and I created the project in vs code and added the font awesome CSS link from w3schools.com as I usually do but it shows me rectangles then I also tried adding font awesome CSS link from cdnpkg.com but the result is same. Here's my `<head>` (also check for `<meta>` errors):

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/fontawesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
```

Also, I checked if the FontAwesome CSS is loaded in the web browser and it was loaded and applied correctly (as checked on sources tab in developer options window).
How I used:

```html
<body>
    <i class='fa fa-twitter'></i>
</body>
```

I also tried changing font-family to 'FontAwesome', 'FontAwesome 5 Free', ... and the font-weight is normal.

Here are the issues (issues panel in developer options) in my project for reference:

```
The 'x-ua-compatible' meta element should not be specified as it is not needed.
A 'cache-control' header is missing or empty.
FontAwesome: Static resources should use a 'cache-control' header with 'max-age=31536000' or more.
FontAwesome: Static resources should use a 'cache-control' header with the 'immutable' directive.
Response should include 'x-content-type-options' header.
```

Comment: The error file says it isn't compatible, which is your Windows version?

Comment: @Harsh Windows 10 21h1

Comment: Is your HTML document saved in UTF-8? Just declaring it in the `head` does not make it UTF-8, you also have to convert it. For example, [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) can convert from ANSI into UTF-8 for you (*Encoding* -> *Convert to UTF-8*). You can set UTF-8 as default.

Comment: VS Code's status bar says 'UTF-8' which clarifies that the file is utf-8 encoded. Also checking the file for charset on an online platform tells that the file US-ASCII encoded which is a subset of UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

This will work!
Remove this line from your `<header>` :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

And add this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8; X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
```

Explanation:
The first error is pretty self-explanatory as it is not needed,

Secondly, cache-control is required to hold instructions...

I am not very familiar with the X-content thing ([you can read more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337630/what-is-x-content-type-options-nosniff)) but it is required according to your console error, remove that line if font awesome still doesn't load.

The meta errors will surely be cleared though! Hope this was helpful!

**EDIT:**
Use this in your code, it may or may not work...

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, immutable"
</FilesMatch>
```

This much can solve the Cache errors your browser is giving because of static elements...Try it and let me know if it works...(:

Comment: I had all the hopes that this would work but it didn't! What the heck!

Comment: OK, @SatyamMishra I might have one more trick in my pocket let me see if that works, I'll edit my answer please check the edited update...

Comment: Thanks for being active in this thread... Can I know where use the tags i.e. inside `<head>` or `<html>` or anywhere else. Well I tried in head element but still no outcomes... but VS code is flagging it as a syntax error ([See Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/cpTFAv8)) and the output screenshot is [here](https://imgur.com/a/qsMOlAI)  which is obvious when you look at the code.

Comment: maybe try this last one,
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public" max-age="31536000">
i've not added 'immutable' in this since its not supported in chrome...

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me but still it didn't work.... I appreciate your work.

Comment: Oh, hope you find a solution, your welcome (: @SatyamMishra

Answer (score 0):

for the error i guess you are missing something

Then i just tried twitter ones from the site it give me also square, and, with this one its ok, may you try?

```
<i class="fas fa-times" style="color: red"></i>
```

here is the code you are missing i think

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="fr">

</html> (at the end)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... But I already tried the transformations you suggested and also my webpage starts with doctype html. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 suggestions for this. First, is to check you are not overwriting the entire web page font family e.g:

```
* {
   font-family: 'sans-serif' !important; 
}
```

if so remove this and apply font-family to the needed assets rather than the whole page and be sure !important tag isn't used.

SECOND:

you could try creating a local directory to save and load the font-awesome stylesheet and fonts rather than loading them via CDN/URL

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions... I tried the first method, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. I would appreciate your second suggestion but I would rather like to work with cdn servers instead storing font-awesome css on my server because the cdn servers are very fast and my server would probably not have that speed. Thanks!