# Servlet html generated code is shown as plain text after nosniff added to httpd.conf file

Tags: java, html, apache

After adding the following line to our Apache **httpd.conf** configuration file, the html code generated by our **servlets** is not interpreted correctly by the browser, but its html code is displayed as **plain text**:

```
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
```

From nothing to served add the following **header** to the code generated by the servlets:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

Neither with this works:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1; X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff" />
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337630/what-is-x-content-type-options-nosniff) (e.g. do your servlets actually generate a header that declares the correct content type, or was it sniffied until now?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, for me, this do the job:

```
httpServletResponse.setContentType("text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1");
```