# What is the correct way to send a long string by an HTTP stream in ExpressJS/NestJS?

Tags: node.js, express, http, openai-api, http-streaming

I'm using NestJS to write a forwarding service for the openai chat completion API. I want to do a transformation for the original stream and then forward stream to the client side.

The code is like below, and it's inside a nestJS controller

```js
const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion(
  {
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
    messages: messages,
    n: 1,
    stream: true,
    max_tokens: 4000,
  },
  { responseType: 'stream' },
);

class TransformerStream extends Transform {
  _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    // If I directly forward the chunk like this, the client can receive chunk by chunk
    this.push(chunk)
    // However, if I use string, the client can't receive chunk by chunk.
    // My original code is to transform the chunk to string and do some transformation, to simplify the question, just use 'data: ping\n' here
    this.push('data: ping\n', 'utf8')
    callback()
  }
}

const transformer = new TransformerStream()
completion.data.pipe(transformer).pipe(res)
```

And I'm using axios to request the API from the client side, and I'm trying to receive it chunk by chunk using `onDownloadProgress`

```js
axios.post('/api/chat', body, {
  responseType: 'stream',
  onDownloadProgress: progress => {
    console.log(progress)
  }
} )
```

In summary, when I directly send the buffer chunk from the openAI api, the progress can be logged several times.
But when I send the string, it can only be logged once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be due to the difference between the length of the original `chunk` and the length of the string you are trying to write to the stream.

You can consider setting the following headers in your NestJS controller:

- `Transfer-Encoding`: `chunked`
- `X-Content-Type-Options`: `nosniff`

Sample code:

```js
res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
res.setHeader('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');
```

`Transfer-Encoding` tells the browser to start processing the data instead of waiting for all the content to be loaded first

`X-Content-Type-Options` tells the browser to respect the `Content-Type` specified by your header instead of trying to guess based on the head of the content returned. Based on my test with latest Chrome browser, it seems like the initial 1024 bytes are "blocked" before browser correctly identified the `Content-Type`.

You can read more about the behaviour here: [What is "X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337630/what-is-x-content-type-options-nosniff)

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options

Comment: Thanks. Adding the `X-Content-Type-Options` helps. The `Transfer-Encoding` is added by the server automatically. Now the xhr's progress event can be triggered.

Comment: I also found if I add `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`, without the `nosniff` header, the progress event can also be triggered. And the explaination seems to be that if sniffing will happen when the `Content-Type` is not specified or wrong.