# OpenAI Stream response, not working as expected

Tags: node.js, express, openai-api

On my NodeJS app, i have set-up a `POST` method that looks like this:

```
exports.complete = async (req, res, next) => {\
    const {prompt} = req.body
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
    })
    const result = await openai.createCompletion(
    {
      model: 'text-davinci-003',
      prompt: prompt,
      temperature: 0.6,
      max_tokens: 700,
      stream: true
    },
    { responseType: 'stream' }
  )

  result.data.on('data', data => {
    const lines = data
      .toString()
      .split('\n')
      .filter(line => line.trim() !== '')
    for (const line of lines) {
      const message = line.replace(/^data: /, '')
      if (message === '[DONE]') {
          res.end()
      }
      try {
        const parsed = JSON.parse(message)
        res.write(parsed.choices[0].text)
      } catch (error) {
        // console.error('Could not JSON parse stream message', message, error)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

As the OpenAI Node SDK doesn't natively support streaming responses, i scrapped this code from a few sources.

To some extent, it is working i guess. But when i make a call to this endpoint from Postman and also from command line (using `curl`), instead of actually getting the response in chunks, i am getting a final response when the entire `completion` call finishes.

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here. **Note:** This code above is a part of a Firebase Function call where i have set-up `express`. I don't think it affects anything, but still mentioning.

**Edit 1: The `curl` request**

Here's my `curl` request:

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:5001/testapp-7aca9/us-central1/api/completion/complete' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "message": "Say two random lines"
}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the solution posted here: [What is the correct way to send a long string by an HTTP stream in ExpressJS/NestJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76080243/what-is-the-correct-way-to-send-a-long-string-by-an-http-stream-in-expressjs-nes)

It might be caused by 2 reasons:

1. In `curl`, you will need to add `-N` flag to buffer the response to receive the response directly
2. In browser, the data are not returned until at least 1024 bytes (for Chrome) is returned, unless you add a `X-Content-Type-Options` of `nosniff`

Comment: I am soo stupid! I was using the `curl` snippet i got from Postman, which excluded the `-N` flag. It is working as expected now!