# Is there a timeout to the 'response.write' method in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using a Mongoose cursor to retrieve a big amount of data in parts and send it progressively as I receive each part. To do this, I use the method `res.write()`.

```
cursor.on('data', (doc) => {
  /*Array opening bracket only sent at the start*/
  if (total === 0) {
    res.write('[');
  }
  docs.push(doc);
  total += 1;

  /*Limit indicates each CSV length*/
  if (docs.length === limit) {
    res.write(JSON.stringify(docs));
    res.write(',');
    docs = [];
  }
});

cursor.on('end', (doc) => {
  ...
  /*Closing bracket sent after the array is completed*/
  res.write(']');
  ...
  res.end();
});
```

As seen in the code above, I have a variable ***limit*** to know when to write the next part of the response. If this variable is too big, it requires more time to assemble each part, and the query finishes before I could write it. (If I reduce this variable, it works fine).

When this happens, the response only contains the string: `'['`. As if it would have called the method `res.end()` after a certain amount of time.

My question is: Is there a timeout when you use the `res.write()` method, after which (if you don't keep writing or send the response) `res.end()` is called? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `response.write` is a node.js method
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no timeout for `res.write`. If you look at the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) however, while the headers are implicitly set the first time `response.write` is invoked, they might not be exactly what you want

I would try to explicitly set these headers before sending out data, i.e. when you receive the request:

```
response.setHeader('Connection', 'Transfer-Encoding');
response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
response.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
```

I would also add a simple check to `response.write` to make sure that each chunk is flushed:

```js
  /*Limit indicates each CSV length*/
  if (docs.length === limit) {
    let chunk = JSON.stringify(docs);
    if(res.write(`${chunk},`)) {
      docs = [];
    } else {
      console.log(`oops! something is wrong with chunk ${chunk}`);
    }
  }
```

Finally, I would read up this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16999405/3253893 to understand why this might be a bad idea if you expect more than one query at a time